# Pivot Table with varchar values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, varchar

this is the first-time I use this and I hope i will achieve this, I am getting mad. I am still a newbie about all this programming with SQL thing, I am trying to use pivot table to turn the source table in the desired output showed as below.

This is my source table

Here is the image, I was unable to upload it (https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDStF.jpg).
[image]

But whatever I try it returns me numbers but the varchar values I would like to, as it is shown above.
Would any of you know how to achieve it?

I am using Transact SQL in Sql Server, here is my code

```
SELECT [Ques1], [Ques2]
FROM
(
  SELECT
    D.DocumentId,
    DA.QuestionId,
    Q.ShortText, 
    DA.[Text],
    Q.SectionId, 
    1 as [Count]
-- ShortText is literally 'Ques1' or 'Ques2'
    FROM Document D
    INNER JOIN DocumentAnswer DA
    ON DA.DocumentId = D.DocumentId
    INNER JOIN Question Q
    ON Q.QuestionId = DA.QuestionId
    WHERE D.DeleteDate IS NULL
) d  
PIVOT
(
    Max(ShortText)
    FOR [Text] IN ([Ques1], [Ques2])
) p
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/41255)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (DocID INT, Ques VARCHAR(100), Ans VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES 
(1 , 'Ques1' , 'Hola'),
(1 , 'Ques2' , 'Padr'),
(2 , 'Ques1' , 'Excue'),
(2 , 'Ques2' , 'Dir')

SELECT * FROM
( -- Put your existing query here
 SELECT * FROM @TABLE
) t
  PIVOT (MAX(Ans)
         FOR Ques 
         IN ([Ques1],[Ques2])
         )p
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/41255/0)**:

```
| DOCID | QUES1 | QUES2 |
|-------|-------|-------|
|     1 |  Hola |  Padr |
|     2 | Excue |   Dir |
```

Comment: I know it's an old answer but anyway...
What if there is no DocID, just Ques and Ans columns? Then pivoting will take only one value for each Ques (Ques1 and Ques2), min or max, depending on aggregate function used. Is it possible to display them all?